# Smooth transitions hover images

Tags: css, image, transactions, hover, css-transitions

I've tried to solve a problem for hours and I would really appreciate some help.

The goal is to get a "smoother transition" when the image shift when you hover over it. I played around with opacity etc and nothing works.

HTML Code:

```
<div class="montage">
    <p>Add</p>
    <img id="montage" src="Imagesnya/montage2.jpg" alt="">
</div>
<div class="borttagning">
    <p>Remove</p>
    <img id="borttagning" src="Imagesnya/borttagning3.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.borttagning {
    margin-left: 9%;
    margin-top: 31%;
    position: absolute;
}

.borttagning img {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    opacity: 0;
}

.borttagning:hover img {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
       -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
         -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
            transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

#borttagning {
    width: 64.0%;
    margin-top: 5.8%;
    margin-left: -24.25%;
}

.montage {
    margin-left: 18%;
    margin-top: 10%;
    position: absolute;
}

.montage img {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    opacity: 0;
}

.montage:hover img {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
       -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
         -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
            transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
#montage{ 
    width: 64.0%;
    margin-top: -13.7%;
    margin-left: -23.53%;
}
```

Anyone who knows what I've done wrong?

Comment: If it helps explaining what I mean, here's the website (as you can see the "shift" between the images is to "fast", I want it to be more of a "delay".

www.bildredigering.nu/nyhemsida/backup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this : http://jsfiddle.net/3fvn8uoa/3/

Adding `transition` on normal state instead of `:hover` will do the thing (However according to me your code should also work)

Update:
Saw the link to the website you provided in the comment to the question, there you are transitioning b/w `display: none` to `display: block`, that can't and won't be smooth because transition of `display` property is not supported. You'll have implement things as shown in the above jsfiddle

Comment: Thank you! I will try this :)!

Comment: Welcome! :D Also don't forget to accept my answer if it works ;P